# Capistrano change user after ssh log-in - deploy as another user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ssh, capistrano, capistrano3

In my staging.rb file i need to connect with "ubuntu" username

```
server '**.**.****.**', user: 'ubuntu',  roles: %w{web app db}
```

In my deploy.rb

```
set :deploy_to, -> { "/var/www/myuser/myuser.com/capi" }
```

Server

```
var/www/myuser/myuser.com# ls -la
total 32
drwxrwx--- 8 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  9 14:54 .
drwxrwx--- 5 myuser myuser 4096 Feb 26 17:18 ..
drwxrwx--- 7 myuser myuser 4096 May  7 13:48 beta
drwxr-xr-x 2 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  9 14:54 capi
drwxrwx--- 9 myuser myuser 4096 May  8 20:15 quiz
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser myuser 4096 May  8 20:10 scoreboards
drwxrwx--- 2 myuser myuser 4096 May  8 20:10 stats
drwxrwx--- 7 myuser myuser 4096 Jul  2 14:58 www
```

when i do "bundle exec cap staging deploy" i have this error

```
 mkdir stderr: mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/myuser': Permission denied
 mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/myuser': Permission denied
```

How i can change user with capistrano?

Comment: could you not add the `ubuntu` user to the `myuser` group? `useradd -G myuser ubuntu`

Comment: useradd: user 'ubuntu' already exists

Comment: whoops, of course. Try `usermod -a -G myuser ubuntu` to add the `ubuntu` user to `myuser` group.

Comment: Now there is this error

mkdir stderr: mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/myuser/myuser.com/capi/shared': Permission denied
mkdir: cannot create directory '/var/www/myuser/myuser.com/capi/releases': Permission denied

Comment: do all the files in the `capi` directory also belong to the `myuser` user and group? `cd capi` then do `ls -a` again.

Comment: ok sorry... now it's ok all works... 
But i don't like this solution...
how I can, after deploy, set all to myuser group permission?

Comment: I"ve not used capistrano, do you mean execute a command to `chown` some files after a deploy? Also, are some files being changed from `myuser` during the deployment process for some reason?